# How to get a subset of a matlab table?

Tags: matlab

I have a Matlab table A. I want to extract some rows from the table by certain key words and put the result into another table.

tmpTbl = wthr_prices('ATL CDD',:,'7/7/2015', :,:, :)

But it keeps saying error. I am totally confused here.

Thanks!

Comment: new=old(1:3,:). This?

Comment: [Matrix Indexing in MATLAB](http://uk.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html) and [How to ask on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) would be good readings to start.

Comment: Ander, Thanks.  It should be, but I have some key workds that have to match. For example, The new will be all the rows in column 1 of old that match a key word, say, " Hey. I got it. It should be here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-table.html I am going to try it.

Comment: I think the answer is here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-table.html How do I choose this as an answer?

Comment: Oops. I still get errors: unrecognized row name. Besially, I don't have a row name. What can I do?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you have up no now and an example of what you want to achieve.

Comment: I tried to edit the original question but always get errors. And I don't know what is wrong with that since there is no explain.

Comment: Here is an edited version: I have a Matlab table A. I want to extract some rows from the table by certain key words and put the result into another table.

I have a large table, with 3000 rows and 6 columns.
The first column is 'symbols', the 3rd column is 'dates'.

I want to get a subset of the table, such that the first column contains 
symbols = 'ABC' and 3rd column dates = '7/7/2015'

So I want it to be something like:

newtbl = oldTbl({'ABC', :, '7/7/2015', :,:,:}, :)


Thanks!

Comment: Please read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on how to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example. After this, edit your question completely to include what is missing, so we can reproduce the error.

Comment: My problem is that I am new here, I don't know how to create a neat question. What I wrote in the editing area does not show as I typed. It is frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution:

```
mask=strcmpi(myTable.mycolumn(:), 'my string')
newtable = myTable(mask, :)
```